# Entering ';' while vertical editing in Visual Studio breaks editing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I like [vertical editing](http://www.visualstudiotipsandtricks.com/blog/2013/04/20/select-and-edit-vertical-blocks/) in Visual Studio, and use it a lot. And it was surprise for me that when I enter just `;` symbol - vertical editing stops. Result is - I cannot enter `;` to many rows at one time. Does anybody know why it works like that?

I don't want to say that it is a bug and I'm looking for any fix. I'm just curios what is the reason for such decision of VS development team.

Comment: I am not seeing this issue in VS 2013 when I attempt to duplicate.  I can type `;` and it still is in vertical edit mode.  Is it possible you have an extension that is causing this behavior?

Comment: @stephen.vakil Do you have https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/ ?

Comment: Yes.  I have tried with it turned on and with it entirely turned off and it doesn't seem to affect vertical editing with `;`

Comment: @stephen.vakil it seemed to me that Resharper makes some 'refactoring' after entering `;`, but if you don't have the same issue and have resharper, it is something magic

Comment: could be different options enabled between us.  Does the issue persist if you disable resharper, restart, and try again?